# Extract letters from a string in R

Tags: r, string, data-manipulation

I have a character vector containing variable names such as `x <- c("AB.38.2", "GF.40.4", "ABC.34.2")`. I want to extract the letters so that I have a character vector now containing only the letters e.g. `c("AB", "GF", "ABC")`.

Because the number of letters varies, I cannot use `substring` to specify the first and last characters.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can try

```
sub("^([[:alpha:]]*).*", "\\1", x)
[1] "AB"  "GF"  "ABC"
```

Comment: Or `sub("[^[:alpha:]]+", "", x)`

Comment: Or, with `library( "stringr" )`, a bit more legible: `str_extract(x, "[A-Z]+" )`

Comment: vaettchen how would it be if I want to use spanish characters such as "ñ"

Answer (score 16):

The previous answers seem more complicated than necessary. [This question](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/removing-all-non-numeric-characters-from-a-string-but-not-quot-quot-td4723146.html) regarding digits also works with letters:

```
> x <- c("AB.38.2", "GF.40.4", "ABC.34.2", "A B ..C 312, Fd", "  a")
> gsub("[^a-zA-Z]", "", x)
[1] "AB"    "GF"    "ABC"   "ABCFd" "a"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I managed to solve this problem. I use this because it returns the 5 items cleanly and I can control if i want a space in between the words:

```html
x <- c("AB.38.2", "GF.40.4", "ABC.34.2", "A B ..C 312, Fd", "  a")

extract.alpha <- function(x, space = ""){      
  require(stringr)
  require(purrr)
  require(magrittr)
  
  y <- strsplit(unlist(x), "[^a-zA-Z]+") 
  z <- y %>% map(~paste(., collapse = space)) %>% simplify()
  return(z)}

extract.alpha(x, space = " ")
```

Comment: by the way, readr has functions to handle text/character separation, check out readr::parse_number()
readr::parse_character()
readr::parse_date()

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers work if you have mixed letter with spaces. Here is what I'm doing for those cases:

```
x <- c("AB.38.2", "GF.40.4", "ABC.34.2", "A B ..C 312, Fd")
unique(na.omit(unlist(strsplit(unlist(x), "[^a-zA-Z]+"))))
```

> [1] "AB"  "GF"  "ABC" "A"   "B"   "C"   "Fd"

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question but since I was looking for a similar answer just now and found it, I thought I'd share.

The simplest and fastest solution I found myself:

```
x <- c("AB.38.2", "GF.40.4", "ABC.34.2")
only_letters <- function(x) { gsub("^([[:alpha:]]*).*$","\\1",x) }
only_letters(x)
```

And the output is:

```
[1] "AB"  "GF"  "ABC"
```

Hope this helps someone!